# Observable.just for rxdart: ^0.26.0

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, rxdart

I have the new rxdart: ^0.26.0 version, and I know `Observable` got deprecated and you can use `Stream` instead, question is, how do I use `Observable.just` for the newer version?

Comment: any simple example?

Comment: `return Observable.just({})` was what you would use a while back, but since the rxdart package got updated it is no longer available, if I wanted my code to do what `Observable.just` did a while back, what would I use?

Answer (score 1):

I found it on package's [changelog](https://pub.dev/packages/rxdart/changelog)

---

`Observable.just` has been replaced with `Stream.value`